# Submodule update between branches

Tags: git, git-submodules

The master was bumped to point to the HASH_5 few days ago, and I see this commit on master.
Now I have rebased my feature branch from the master and I expected that the submodule in my feature branch will point to HASH_5. However, it still points to HASH_1 and I don't see any way to move it to the one master points on.
All the update options for the submodule uses either the hash from the superproject  or from the remote origin (or HASH_1 or HASH_10).
When I run git log on my feature branch, I see the commit from the master that bumps the submodule to HASH_5 - but the commit doesn't really contain any files. As far as I know, current submodule's hash is stored directly in the Git object store.
Anyone has an idea how to move the submodule in the feature branch to the commit master is pointing on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the parent repo.
`$ git submodule update`

From the docs:

> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject
>   expects by cloning missing submodules and updating the working tree of
>   the submodules. The "updating" can be done in several ways depending
>   on command line options and the value of submodule..update
>   configuration variable. The command line option takes precedence over
>   the configuration variable. If neither is given, a checkout is
>   performed...

You can add a post-checkout hook to do this automatically.

However, this will only update if your submodules were pushed correctly before the parent project was committed.  If not, those changes in your submodules are lost. If you want to make sure that this is or isn't the case:
    cd 
    git log

If you see the commits, in the submodules history, then you are good.

The way to make changes in your submodule is
    cd 
    git branch 
    git commit
    git push
    cd 
    git commit

The commit and push in the submodules are required if you don't want to lose your changes.